# Strange image load problem html/php

Tags: css, image, html

I have been trying to solve this strange problem with a website I am designing.  The image for the logo doesn't load in Firefox - you need to hover your mouse over the ALT text that is displayed, and the logo will then load.

This does not happen in IE - where the logo loads as it should.

This just started happening, and I cannot seem to find a resolution.  I even changed the logo to a different image with similar results.

Has anyone ever encountered something similar?  Any suggestions on what to look for to fix this?

EDIT:  I also have setup a .htaccess/.htpasswd for security while the site is setup.

Comment: Sample code and mime type of the images might help.

Comment: It is a GIF file.  I might be able to whip up some sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the logo have a position absolute or static around position: relative items? I've seen this happen is strange cases like this.

Comment: #logo{margin: 5px auto; position: relative; font-size: 0.75em; width: 940px; height: 30px;}
#logo img{ float:left;}

Comment: Nothing is set to absolute or static

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Nevermind.  Looks like it is intermittent.  This only fixed it for a few refreshes.

I have a jquery script that was causing the issue.  I was doing the following in my HEAD tag:

```
<script src="http://www.SITE.com/scripts/scroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.SITE.com/scripts/jquery.scrollfollow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The scroll.js script is dependant on the scrollfolow.js plugin.  I just swapped the lines so that scrollfollow.js loaded first.  This solved the issue with the LOGO gif file.

Anyone able to explain this?